# Properties of transpose matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

It's known that if $A$ is a matrix such that $A.A^T = 0$  then $A = 0$

Suppose I let $A = (a_{ij} )$ be $m×n$ matrix and $A^T = (a_{ji})$ be its transpose.

However, I do not understand how do i go about proving the quoted concept above.

Comment: Hint: suppose some entry of the matrix is not zero. Do some $2 \times 2$ example with that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $A$ has rows $r_1=(a_{1,1},a_{1,2},...,a_{1,n}),...,r_m=(a_{m,1},a_{m,2},...,a_{m,n})$, then $AA^T$ has diagonal entries $r_1 \cdot r_1, r_2 \cdot r_2,...,r_m \cdot r_m.$